# Local push notification to Win8 Live Tile running JS code inside app

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-8, winjs, live-tile

I am trying to send updates to my app's tile.  This works fine when the app is running.  I can, for example, easily send a tile update notification to the tile when the user clicks a button.

What I can't work out is how to update the tile when the app isn't working.  The only option I have found for this is to poll (or push from) a remote webserver using `REST` on `HTTP`.  This isn't ideal for me, and I cannot believe that is the only method of updating the tile.

Ideal here would be to specify a local JS file that is to get run at any given interval, let's say 15 mins as per the Tile guidelines.

As stated I am using JavaScript throughout, not C#.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of choices.  You can implement a Background task for your application that can update the tile.  See the [Background Quickstart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977045.aspx) for info on getting started with that.   [Day 21 of GenerationApp](http://aka.ms/30Days) also provides more info on working with background tasks.

Another option is to use Push Notifications.  You can read the [overview of Push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx) and also checkout [Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) for an easy way to provision notifications in the cloud.

Comment: Looks like the background task is what I need.  Thanks